# Not understanding OOP for virtual and protected set

Tags: c#, inheritance

Hi I thought I was understanding these concepts but I am not sure anymore.

Let's say I have the following:

Interface

```
public interface IUnit
{
    DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Base class

```
public abstract class UnitBase : IUnit
{
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDateTime
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
    DateTime IUnit.CreatedDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatedDateTime;
        }
        set
        {
            CreatedDateTime = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have another class which inherits from UnitBase

```
public class NewClass : UnitBase
{
}
```

NewClass contains the property of CreatedDateTime since it inherits from UnitBase, and since NewClass didn't override it, I suppose it still has the protected accessor for set.

So if I were to create a new instance of NewClass:

```
NewClass obj = new NewClass();
obj.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;  //This is not allowed
```

but why can I cast the obj to IUnit and modify it?

```
//like this
((IUnit)obj).CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now  //Allowed?
```

I thought protected set can only set its value in the scope of the class it declared (UnitBase), and classes inherited from it (NewClass).  So how come I can cast it and modified it like that?  And what's the point of protected set if that is allowed?  I am not quite understanding what's going on here.  Could someone explain to me?

Edit: Sry I have modified the code, it should compile now.  So, if I were able to cast it to IUnit and change the value, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of protected set?  Can I change the modifiers in the interface so I cannot cast to IUnit and modify values ?

Comment: That shouldn't compile.

Comment: Your code does not compile. There's something going on here that you're not telling us.  Your analysis is correct; that should be illegal and *it is illegal*.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it.

Comment: OK, with the new edits then I don't see what the problem is.  You now have four members: two public getters, one public setter and a protected setter. The protected setter is *never accessed by name outside of its accessibility domain*, which is the class and its derived classes. So what's the problem? The person who chose to leak access to the protected setter is *you*; if it hurts when you do that then *don't do that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface IUnit specifies a setter. This implies that the setter is public which is why you are allowed to set it by casting to IUnit.

If you want implementations of IUnit to be able to specify their own access modifer for set, only specify that the get has to be public in the interface like this:

```
public interface IUnit
{
    DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; }
}
```

Comment: but the setter in UnitBase class must be public in order to implement IUnit. OP code is illegal.

Comment: @jure I agree, I was just trying to explain that interfaces enforce things to be public, in case that was misunderstood.

Comment: @iyuu I see that. To answer your question "Can I change the modifiers in the interface so I cannot cast to IUnit and modify values ?" Why dont you just not specify the set; in the interface like i propose in my answer, then each implementing class can create a setter with different access modifiers if they choose to?

Answer (score 0):

As far as you cast the `obj` to the `IUnit` and `IUnit`, the compiler treat it as an `IUnit` so you can set the `CreateDateTime` and nothing is wrong or special.

Moreover your code won't compile. because `UnitBase` is not implementing the `IUnit`. To reach what you are looking for you may edit your `UnitBase` as follow:

```
public class UnitBase : IUnit
{
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; protected set; }

    DateTime IUnit.CreatedDateTime
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface defines a contract that contract says that CreateDateTime has a public get / set.  Once you cast that object it treats the object as the interface and the interface has a public set.

If that was not the case any function which takes a IUnit would have to dynamical determine the true type of the object and then see if the access modifiers applied.  That would mean that static linking would not apply any time you pass in a virtual object and that derived children could change the meaning of interfaces. Think of what that would imply when you talk about seperatly build assemblies